# creating a forest plot in R

Tags: r

I want to create a forest plot in R from the following data set:

```
        Cohort1  Cohort2 Cohort3 Cohort4 Cohort5   
Gene1    0.009    0.016   0.019   0.048   0.53 
Gene2     0.97    0.004   0.032   0.018   0.023
Gene3    0.003    0.0003  0.008   0.032   0.884
Gene4    0.003    0.0024  0.486   0.436   0.035
Gene5    0.029    0.027   0.073   0.033   0.061
```

I want p value (the values in my table) on the x value (rather than odds-ratio as usual) and cohort on the y axis with a 95% confidence interval for each gene

I've been looking at all the various methods - `ggplot2`, `metaplot`, `forestplot` etc but I can't really work out how to do this. Can anyone give some advice?

It appears I need to specify the centres & the standard error?

Comment: Where do you store the confidence intervals?

Comment: I don't have any stored. I assumed that the forest plot function would calculate the confidence interval, which seemed to be the case with some methods?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a geneticist; just trying to help. As I understand it, forest plots compare the average response for different treatments. Here "treatment" is the Cohort. So wouldn't you need five forest plots, 1 for each gene? Or do you want the average p-value across genes?? Also, to impute confidence interval from p you would need to know the sample size (degrees of freedom).